# How To Change the action of Context Menu key in VS Code?

Tags: context-menu

By default, the action of the context menu key in VS Code editor is opening the context menu. I want to change its function to run a script or execute a program for example, I tried to do that from keyboard shortcuts settings, but I didn't.

Although I set the shortcut key (context menu) for the function that I want to perform (run a script or execute a program in terminal ...), but the context menu key function still works (when I click on the context menu key, the context menu stills appear) this is a picture

[image]

- (I want to disable the context menu from appear) - is that possible to do (Knowing that this can be done in PyCharm ...):

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

- Anybody can help? I'll appreciate it, Thanks.

Comment: Did the answer help? I see you keep asking a bunch of AHK questions without resolving this one.

Comment: No, I can't change the change the action of Context Menu key in VS Code, but I found another solution.

Comment: So post the solution, please. Mine should definitely work too, but if you found something yourself and expect help from people here, you should also help other people.

Comment: #If WinActive("2kha.ahk")
 AppsKey::
 send ^{SC029}
 CoordMode, ToolTip, Screen
 ToolTip 2kha,1555,1400
 Sleep, 1000
 Run, "%A_ScriptFullPath%" ;Reload
 Return

Comment: No, I meant as an answer. Like mine below. With some explantation as to why this is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be impossible within VSCode indeed, as suggested by old issues like [this](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/14478) and lack of visible binding in shortcut listing.

As a workaround, you can use [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) and rebind the `AppsKey` (`ContextMenu`) key to an unused combination just when VSCode [window is active](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/_IfWinActive.htm), then use that combination for your program/script binding.

Example of `script.ahk`:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_exe Code.exe
AppsKey::Send {Shift Down}{Ctrl Down}{Alt Down}6{Alt up}{Ctrl Up}{Shift Up}
```

Would bind it to <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>6</kbd>